# How can I load a wav file in R using a URL of the wav file?

Tags: r, url, audio, wav

I am developing a Shiny application, in which I currently load wav-files by using `audio::load.wave(path to wav-file)`

However, I have to publish the Shiny application online, and thus I have to be able to load the wav-files from a URL.
In the past, I was able to read data by using `dataTable <- read.table("URL")`

For the audio file I already tried using `load(url("URL to wav file"))` or `loadwave(url("URL"))`. However, nothing works.
Does anyone have an idea of how to load a wav-file using a URL in R? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible workaround might be to temporary download the audio file on the server, load it in the shiny app, and then remove it at the end of the session.

Here is a sample code:

```
url <- "http://www.wavlist.com/humor/001/911d.wav"

# Define the temporary directory and download the data
dest_path <- "sound.wav"
download.file(url,destfile = dest_path)

# Load the audio file
audio::load.wave(dest_path)

# At the end of the session remove the downloaded data
file.remove(dest_path)
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. However, if I play the wav-file then with R (audio::play), it sounds extremely distorted.